# Google Spreadsheet - SUM Alternate Cells In A Row

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sample scenario below, a spreadsheet with multiple pairs of columns for credit and debit. How can we create a formula to calculate alternate cells in Google Spreadsheet like if we want a sum of all Debits for each of person, without having to specifically select the cells? I tried looking for ways perhaps using FILTER but it doesn't work (Like SUM(FILTER(COLUMN(B3:G3),ISODD)). Is there a way to do this using a formula?

[image]

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76068515/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your `B3:G3` example for Roger:

for even columns / credit:
`=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN(B3:G3),2)=0)*(B3:G3))`

for odd columns / debit:
`=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN(B3:G3)+1,2)=0)*(B3:G3))`